# "$translateProvider.useLocalStorage" causes (uncaught error)

Tags: javascript, angular-translate

I know this question seems to be asked many times. But for all it is resolved by adding correct script files into the HTML, and in the right order. But me I think it is already my case and I don't know why this Uncaught error is raising again.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-cookie/angular-translate-storage-cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local.min.js"></script>
```

script

```
angular.module('rdvmedecins', [ 'ui.bootstrap',
                                'tmh.dynamicLocale',
                                'ngRoute',
                                'pascalprecht.translate'])

.config(['$translateProvider', 'tmhDynamicLocaleProvider', function($translateProvider, tmhDynamicLocaleProvider) {
            $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
                prefix: 'i18n/messages_',
                suffix: '.json'
            });
            $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');

            $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
            $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
            tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
        }
    ]
)
```

When I comment

> $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();

it works fine.

All needed scripts are imported into the HTML.
They are imported in the right order.

Any other ideas to check? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Well....
The dependancy

> 'ngCookies'

missed into the modules list

```
angular.module('rdvmedecins', [ 'ui.bootstrap',
                                'tmh.dynamicLocale',
                                'ngRoute',
                                'pascalprecht.translate',
                                'ngCookies'])
```

But I already tried but that didn't work. 
I read on other post that could be due to local cache problem. Maybe it was because of that even with 'ngCookies' it didn't work.
But now it's ok. :)